# Blender 2.8 bevel with radius size

Tags: bevel

I'm newbie in Blender. For do practice I found technical part drawing.[image]

I need a bevel with 25mm radius. In the bevel menu there are options offset, width, depth and percent. I tried different options but I couldn't it properly.

[image]

How can I draw this bevel?

The other question is I changed my units to mm. But in the bevel menu If I entered 25mm the result bevel is big so I entered 0.25mm. Is this a problem with unit conversion?

**Edit**
Simply I try to this

[image]

I just want to do this If it is possible

[image]

Comment: Dear @lemon, I examined the link you gave. But I think my problem is different from that.

Comment: I want to draw a bevel with 25mm radius. I don't have a problem with scale. My main object is constant. In the SolidWorks that was so simple.

Comment: Is it possible with bevel or should I draw a cylinder and subtract it from a rectangle with a boolean modifier?

Comment: Have you at least tried to apply the scale?

Comment: @moonboots I couldn't apply to scale. Because it spoils the whole shape.

Comment: What do you mean? Could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: You should not apply to scale, you should apply the scale

Comment: @moonboots I edited my question and add picture.

Comment: as it has been said, you need to apply the scale (Ctrl A)

Comment: I added an answer, that explains the problem deeply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I have couple objects with different scale, that share the same object data. It seems that objects are different, but whey are the same, and bevel operation proceeds on the objects same way, in object scale coordinates.

[image]

But what if I want to do an operation at world scale?

In the case, I shall apply the scale <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> -> **Scale**, so that it will not affect the coordinates.

[image]